# Олимпиадное программирование и java

Tags: java

Ну допустим программа будет работать с простыми числами до 100 000. Пишем программу, которая отдаёт строку вида:

```
int prostie[] = {2,3,5,7,11,13 ...}
```

Вставляем в основную программу (которую будем задавать как решение). Дописываем код. Жмёт `Run... Code is too long...` Гуглим, оказывается там лимит на 64 кб. В нормальных программах такие данные выводятся в отдельный файл. Но в олимпиадах как правило можно сдавать только один файл - сам код. Облом. Что делать?

Comment: Очевидно; искать такой алгоритм, чтобы и исходники, и вспомогательная информация помещались в 64К. Тогда эту самую информацию можно будет засунуть в исходники.

Comment: Попробуйте зазиповать их разделив запятой например. Результат сжатия вставить строкой в код, и потом распаковать. Если все равно не хватит, то можно сэкономить на запятых- записать все простые числа в одну строку без разделителей, но сперва запомнив с каких позиций начинаются двузначные, трехзначные, четырехзначные итд простые числа.  

----------

У меня например все простые числа до 100к разделенные запятой после сжатия заняли 23 кб.

Comment: плохой у Вас архиватор. Очень плохой. я сожму их до 5 кб и распаковываться буде очень быстро.

Comment: Обычный zip :) Зато никакого гемороя, согласен- можно упаковать более эффективно, но писать программу для этого излишне мне кажется. Можно просто в полкилобайта написать решето Эрастофена, и считать, что это архиватор простых чисел :)

Comment: мой вариант в том, что хранить есть смысл только числа вида `6n+1` и `6n+5` для n > 0. Простые до 6 и так понятны. Все числа другого вида больше 6 будут гарантировано составными (это легко доказывается на уровне третьего класса). Это уменьшает кол-во чисел уже в 3 раза. Дальше, эти числа можно хранить по 1 биту на число. В результате в один байт "влазит" 24 числа.

Comment: Неплохо.()[]

Comment: Я [упаковал в 1К](http://pastebin.com/f1Nz4nng) :-) Для распаковки требуется Windows 7.

---
@ReinRaus: *реально* хороший упаковщик должен бы к простым числам применить Эратосфена. Или что-нибудь покруче. (Если смотреть на определение сложности информации по Колмогорову как длины наиболее короткой программы, которая эту информацию выдаёт.)

Comment: Не очень понятно зачем вам добавлять предпосчитанный массив с простыми числами в исходный код, если можно просто в код задачи вставить код функции, считающей эти значения.

Comment: Оптимизация по времени? Предпосчёт простых чисел делается за линию, если один линейный проход критичен для решения задачи, то неверно выбран алгоритм решения. Мне кажется, что автор не знает о существовании [решета Эратосфена с линейным временем работы][1]
[1]: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/prime_sieve_linear
, буду рад если помог ему этим.

Comment: @iksuy: Поскольку задача ограничена константой 10000, у нас всё, что угодно O(1). ТС, насколько мне кажется, надеялся, что предвычисление даст ненулевой выигрыш по времени.

Comment: Я тут прикинул:  
`6n+1, 6n+5` дают уменьшение числового ряда на треть 0,(3)  

`30n+1, 30n+7, 30n+11, 30n+13, 30n+17, 30n+19, 30n+23, 30n+29`  
уменьшают на 4/15 это 0,2(6)  
`350n+1, 350n+7 ... `  
65/350 равно 0.(1857142)  
`3850n+1 ...`  
530/3850=0.13766233766  
Дальше лень, интересно, какой предел ?

Comment: @ReinRaus: практически уверен, что ноль. Но это не поможет, т. к. чтобы загнать процент в рамки `< ε`, надо подсчитать достаточно много начальных членов последовательности.

Интересно подсчитать, до какого места будет всё ещё выигрыш. Но это вопрос на маткод.

Comment: выигрыш будет, причем постоянный. В качестве базиса оптимально выбирать произведение простых чисел от 2 и до n. Тогда кол-во проверяемых чисел равно произведению этих простых чисел, уменьшенных на единицу (каждое). То есть, для 2*3*5 будет 1*2*4 / (2*3*5) = 4/15.

При 2..43 (а это уже больше 10^16) это будет около 14%. При простых до 1000 выходит около 8%. Но там число уже больше 10 в 957. Для обычных программистов этого больше, чем достаточно :)

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что в С было ограничение на 64 КБ тела main. Может и тут тоже? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно хранить простые числа через битовую маску. Это очень эффективно и влазит в лимит памяти.

Приведу код на Scala, потому что там уже есть готовая структура данных BitSet:

```
// Простые числа до 500 (для 100000 аналогично, только массив побольше будет)
val bitMask = Array(2891462833508853932L,
    -9222764410617429368L,
    -9212077268751349240L,
    577166812715155618L,
    2488238931731062914L,
    -8637762788791285760L,
    613193408596549664L,
    2261147810570754L)

BitSet.fromBitMask(bitMask).foreach(println)
```

Т.е. нужно заранее "в оффлайне" подготовить битовую маску через метод BitSet.toBitMask. А BitSet простых чисел можно заполнить любым удобным способом, хоть полным перебором.

Comment: @orionll, Вы серьезно?

--

Сколько места займет битовая маска для всез 32-бит простых чисел?
Считаете, что 512Mbytes это мало?

Да, для 100000 это займет 25000 байт, но все равно не очень впечатляющее сжатие.

Comment: Ну, в постановке задачи ведь сказано, что 100000. Было бы сказано, что 2^32 - был бы другой разговор.